# android: onKeyListener is not fired for ENTER key pressed for multiline EditText

Tags: android, user-interface

I've found a lot of similar questions but all of them don't work for multilines EditText.
If i set `inputType="text"` EditText becomes singleline and returns are just not shown. I also need "Enter" button to be "Enter" button (not "Next" or "Done").

```
content.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    doSmthSpecial();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why it is not invoking ENTER key event. but you can go for another method which serves you same purpose. use [OnEditorActionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.OnEditorActionListener.html).

```
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            doSomethingSpecial();
            return true;
        }
    });
```

this method is invoked when you press ENTER key on EditText.

Comment: for that, observe the text entered in EditText by using TextWatcher (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html)(editText.addTextChangedListener(watcher);) and search for the character '\n' in text.

Comment: this *does not work for multilines* EditText though does work for singleline (just checked for it)

Comment: for multilined EditText the listener is not fired at all on Enter press

Comment: you must be joking) sure i removed onKeyListener

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42021/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-4ntoine)

Answer (score 0):

i have also digged alot of time on internet for this question's solution then,i found this:

```
et.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));

et is you edit text.
```

this,worked like charm for me.

Comment: does not work for me unfortunately. Does inputType makes sense?

Comment: no,it works for me and i don't this that input type effect's that much, because i have use inputtype as android:inputType="none"

Comment: oh, i catched it. dispatchKeyEvent() simulates user Enter press, but when the user presses Enter type the event is still not fired. I need to make onKeyListener fired when the user presses Enter.